# Edirol R-44 mic preamp mods

Tags: edirol, r-44, pre-amp, modification, portable-recorder

I am thinking about upgrading the preamps in my Edirol R-44 as I really like the recorder, but find the mic preamps a little noisy.

If you have modified yours, which mod did you go for and how successful do you think it is?  Is it quieter and has it it changed the tonal balance?

I am also considering 4 Sound Devices MP-1s, which is probably the best option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably better to go for 2 mixpre's or mixpre D's than 4 MP1's! Much less to carry about and less batteries!! A mixpre weighs about the same as an MP1!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd try and find the original mix pres. It is far superior to the mix pre-D. It is just a much warmer unit.